# Delete HEX color codes from a string (PHP)

Tags: php

I started with PHP a few days ago.

I made some querys to my MySQL database and put the results in a table. Everything is OK with this.

Some of the strings I want to show have color codes (HEX colors) so they look like this:

```
vMafia|#FF00FFKarevan
#Jho#FF0000ny
```

etc. and I want to make them look like this:

```
vMafia|Karevan
#Jhony
```

I tried using `preg_replace`, but I don't really know what to replace exactly. Hope I explained my problem in a understandable way and sorry if I made mistakes in my grammar.

Comment: Make sure to click the green check to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the code below's preg_replace, it's searching for a six character hex code starting with a number sign and replacing it with blank :)

```
<?
$string = 'Jho#FF0000ny';

echo preg_replace("/#[a-f0-9]{6}/i", "", $string); // Outputs Jhony
```

Comment: Mwahaha, isn't that the awesome excitement of stack overflow? I swear I feel like a race car driver on this website trying to win the race, the beauty is, that we all win using this site :)

Comment: Point well taken! I've changed the regex to go from a-f :)

Comment: Worked! Lots of thanks both. Could you believe I have been with this for 7 hours already by myself? Big thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome, at the very least, I'm glad you put forth the effort on your own time, but remember that there's plenty of eager people ready and willing to help when a problem becomes too "weird" to put it in a different light. Sometimes simple problems, take the most time, because we just need a different perspective on the problem :)

Comment: By the way, I'd really appreciate it if you accepted my answer, if it truly helped solve your problem :)

Comment: I have just made it, sorry for not doing yesterday, I didnt knew about that since im new in here. But I accepted it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

`preg_replace('/#[a-f0-9]{6}/i', '', $your_string)`